# Link Information from Different Files One Below Another

Tags: google-bigquery

Good morning guys,

I'm Brazilian, and unfortunately I don't know how to speak English, so I'm using Google Translate.

My question is the following,

I work with several external databases that I generate files and carry out processing using bigquery,

Today I work with a sequence of information:

Date, time, shift, platform, form, value.

Reports have different sizes in relation to the number of lines. So what I wanted to do is generate a select that includes information below the previous information.

Ex.

Date, time, shift, platform, form, value.
2023/10/03, 08:53:21, Morning, Cielo, Credit, 23.52 ---- Information from File 1
2023/10/03, 09:13:11, Morning, Ticket, Meal, 75.21 ------ Information coming from File 2
...

Another issue is that each file has its own header, and using bigquery I perform the select to keep only the information I need. I want the report to only consider the header of the first file, the others would not be necessary, as they would be the same.

Other information, I'm new to using Bigquery.

Comment: Check [pt.so] if that's easier.